# Porting to JBoss 7.1.1 and Seam 2.3, seam.properties

Tags: jboss7.x, seam2

I am porting an application from Seam 2.2 on JBoss 4.2.2 to Seam 2.3 on JBoss 7.1.1

I have a class that picks up its properties from the seam.properties file and it worked perfectly on JBoss 4.2.2. However it is no longer setting the properties in JBoss 7.1.1

Does anyone know how to fix this, or an alternative method for setting properties.

Comment: I have decided to use components.xml to set properties as a workaround. (and it is working)